# C++ nested constructor calls vs. function declaration

Tags: c++, function, constructor, declaration, definition

What is the difference between the code snippets labeled "version 1" and "version 2" in the following code section:

```
int main() {
  using namespace std;
  typedef istream_iterator<int> input;

  // version 1)
  //vector<int> v(input(cin), input());

  // version 2)
  input endofinput;
  vector<int> v(input(cin), endofinput);
}
```

As far as I understand "version 1" is treated as function declaration. But I don't understand why nor what the arguments of the resulting function `v` with return type `vector<int>` are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why

Because the Standard says, more or less, that anything that can possibly be interpreted as a function declaration will be, in any context, no matter what.

> what the arguments... are

You might not believe this, but it's true. `input(cin)` is treated as `input cin`; in this spot, parentheses are allowed and simply meaningless. However, `input()` is not treated as declaring a parameter of type `input` with no name; instead, it is a parameter of type `input(*)()`, i.e. a pointer to a function taking no arguments and returning an `input`. The (*) part is unnecessary in declaring the type, apparently. I guess for the same reason that the `&` is optional when you use a function name to initialize the function pointer...

Another way to get around this, taking advantage of the fact that we're declaring the values separately anyway to justify skipping the typedef:

```
istream_iterator<int> start(cin), end;
vector<int> v(start, end);
```

Another way is to add parentheses in a way that isn't allowed for function declarations:

```
vector<int> v((input(cin)), input());
```

For more information, Google "c++ most vexing parse".

Comment: I'd definitely prefer the later, because the (now invalid, because input iterators are not ForwardIterators and iterating over them invalidates them) iterators won't stay around.

Comment: If you need things not to stick around, you can always just create another scope :) I think the risk of accidentally using the invalid iterators is low, though; why would you be tempted?

Comment: It's more a matter of taste than fear anything wrong will happen. They don't have to be around and they don't need to be named, so I prefer that they are not.

Comment: Probably, the reason they made it so, is to maintain backward compatibility with C.

Answer (score 2):

This is called [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) :

This snippet :

```
  input()
```

could be disambiguated either as

1. a variable definition for variable class input, taking an anonymous instance of class input or
2. a function declaration for a function which returns an object of type input and takes a single (unnamed) argument which is a function returning type input (and taking no input).

Most programmers expect the first, but the C++ standard requires it to be interpreted as the second.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int> v(input(cin), input());
```

Well, the arguments to this function declaration are these:

- `input(cin)` - which is an object
- `input (*)()` - which is a pointer to function returning `input` and taking no argument.